# angularjs ui-router url not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i use ui-router for nested routing in angularjs, it works fine but there is a problem, when i refresh the page or enter the url manually and directly, i get an error:
The requested URL /home/general was not found on this server.
my app code is:

```
angular.module("app",["ui.router"])
.controller("appController",["$scope", function($scope){}])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider){
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: "/library/ngTemplates/home.html"
            })
            .state('home.general', {
                url: "home/general",
                templateUrl: "/library/ngTemplates/home-general.html"
            })
            .state('home.lifeStyle', {
                url: "home/life-style",
                templateUrl: "/library/ngTemplates/home-life-style.html"
            })
            .state('home.lifeStyle.sport', {
                url: "/sport",
                templateUrl: "/library/ngTemplates/home-life-style-sport.html"
            })
            .state('home.lifeStyle.economic', {
                url: "/economic",
                templateUrl: "/library/ngTemplates/home-life-style-economic.html"
            });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Comment: Thats because you dont add this route. Add $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/") to the config and test again please.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735026/angularjs-modifying-the-url-using-locationprovider-html5mode

Comment: where is ur state declaration for purchase-help?

Comment: Here is the FAQ link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735026/angularjs-modifying-the-url-using-locationprovider-html5mode with all the details how to settle UI-Router on the server. If server is properly set, all is working - check the working [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26009350/1679310)

Comment: i added $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/") but still not working

Comment: i edited the question, now the error is ok, there is no purchase help anymore

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
url: "home/general"
```

to

```
url: "/home/general"
```

That first backlash is what's holding your routing back.